# Using PHP variable to fetch data from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a daily question quiz page and I have two database tables with the following names:

1) qbank
2) users_log

Now once the user submits the answer, it takes the user to the grade.php where I access if he/she answered the question correctly. My problem is the following code:

```
$sql = ("SELECT * FROM users_log WHERE username = '$username_wanted'");
$result = $conn->query($sql);
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $myuser = $row["username"];
                    echo $myuser;
                    echo "It found the user";
                    $mycolumn = $row_y[$_POST['question-id']];
                    echo $mycolumn;
                                        }
            }
```

What I would like to do is to select that COLUMN from "users_log" TABLE where the COLUMN name is equal to the question-id from "qbank" table, where the user submitted in the previous page.

Let's just say I define a variable like such:

```
$questionID = "001"
```

What is the correct way of fetching with that variable:

```
$mycolumn = $row_y[$questionID];
```

Thanks,
oliver_foxx

Comment: will you kindly show us the tables structure?

Comment: Structure for the users_log table:
username | 001 | 002 | 003 | etc...

Comment: What are 001,002 and so on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your must construct a query like this (if i understood correctly)

```
$sql = "SELECT username, ".$_POST['question-id']." FROM users_log WHERE username = '".$username_wanted."'";
```

Of course there are some issues here but there are beyond the scope of this question. You may wanna research on these:

1) You are vulnerable to [sql injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

2) I'm not very confident your sql structure is a good one. Seems like you have a column for each question; that sounds terribly [denormalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization)

Comment: I dont think you should ever put raw request data into a query

Comment: @AlexanderHolman i'm specifically telling this in my answer. ***"but there are beyond the scope of this question"***

Comment: thanks, what I'd like to in users_log is to add +/- for each question to see if the user answered correctly or not and get points that. Do you suggest any other alternative design?

Comment: @OliverFox your approach would be good if users must have a record for **all** these questions, and the questions will **never** change, and no questions will **ever added or removed**. Well that sounds highly unlikely. i would suggest a table `users_log` with columns `username,question_id` so you can add and remove questions at will. Also, be sure to see that sql injection problem. To be honest you should go read that right now instead of normalizing/denormalizing your db structure.

Comment: You dont specify why. I just think your example should exclude basic issues like that one

Comment: @AlexanderHolman it's not practical for me to write an essay for every answer that suffers from sql injection. But i always ring the bell, OP can clearly see it, then its up to him if he wants to investigate further.